# Inking for Windows Phone 8.1 (Not Silverlight)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any way to use Inking for Windows phone 8.1 application. I am able to use it in Silverlight application for freehand drawing.

But is there anything available to use for this purpose in WinRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special purpose inking control. You can handle pointer events to track the touch point and draw your own strikes from those positions.

Comment: Do you have an example for this?